# Install headers and libraries for NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, gmp

I am using Android Studio with NDK 20 and CMake.
In the C++ files of my project I use [LinBox](https://linalg.org/linbox-html/dist.html).
For this to work, all of GMP, Givaro, Fflas-Ffpack and of course LinBox itself must be installed.

Trying to accomplish this was a great mess so far (which I do not wish to reproduce here).
Unfortunately, I was not successful.

Could someone give me a hint how to install these headers and libraries?

I expect the difficulty is to figure out the correct parameters for `./configure; make; make install`.
So far I was not able to extract them straightforwardly from the NDK documentation.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#autoconf ?

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. It seems this is what I was looking for. Sorry for not finding this by myself.

Comment: Some tweaking is necessary it seems. For GMP compilation fails with `error adding symbols: File in wrong format`.